# Microsoft Graph List outlookTask not returning immutable ID even if it's in preferred in header

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-sdks

So in the documentation, it says if you want to get tasks with immutable id instead of normal one just add a header 'Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"'. I've done that but it still returns tasks with normal ID.
It works fine when I try it with outlook events and if I try to get outlook task by ID (get single task instead of listing all). But as soon as I try getting all tasks with immutable id it doesn't work. It doesn't say any error it just returns the data but with the normal id.

Also, I know that outlook tasks API is getting deprecated but todo list API is not going to cut it right now and I've already tried it - there is no way to retrieve any form of immutable ids, just normal ones.

This is the code I use to retrieve all tasks (list all tasks) in NodeJS:

```
      let response = await client
        .api('/me/outlook/tasks?$top=25000')
        .header("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"")
        .header('Prefer', `outlook.timezone="${timeZone}"`)
        .version('beta')
        .get();
```

It is very weird because when trying to get one specific task by ID and setting prefer id type header, it works.

Anyway here is how requests look:

**LIST OUTLOOK TASKS (GET ALL OUTLOOK TASKS)**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks
```

**GET ONE SPECIFIC TASK VIA ID**

```
GET /me/outlook/tasks/{id}
```

**HEADER FOR GETTING IMMUTABLE IDS INSTEAD OF NORMAL ONES**

```
Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"
```

**POTENTIONALLY HELPFUL**

This is the code I use to retrieve all events with Immutable ID's (this works compared to tasks)

```
let response = await client.
    api('/me/calendar/events?$top=25000')
    .header('Prefer', `outlook.timezone="${timeZone}"`)
    .header("Prefer", "IdType='ImmutableId'")
    .get();
```

[MS Graph official documentation: How to retrieve a list of outlookTasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

[MS Graph official documentation: outlookTask resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/outlooktask?view=graph-rest-beta)

[MS Graph official documentation: event resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-beta)

[MS Graph official documentation: Get immutable identifiers for Outlook resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id)

Comment: Yes you're correct, the Outlook tasks API is deprecated and will stop returning data on August 20, 2022. So the best bet is the new [To Do API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview) and it's in [public preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/blogs/the-new-improved-microsoft-graph-to-do-apis-are-now-in-public-preview/). So test it with To Do API, see if it supports the immutable functionality, if yes, then try to repro the issue and observe the results.

Comment: @Dev I have tried the To-Do API. It doesn't return immutable ID's. Also, as per the To-Do API documentation, it doesn't look like there is an Immutable ID functionality yet implemented. I have thought about just using extension objects though this will require the code base quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, i checked the docs and thats what i suggested above as well. Definitely you can give a try with your approach, but i fear if there is any changes then (being a public preview), again you need to find another route. Instead my suggestion would be to file a [Microsoft Uservoice / feature request for the To Do API](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=373861), so that they can consider implementing it - it will be a long term solution for you to move forward.

Comment: Does the above helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've found the solution and it's just ridiculous. If any MS Graph SDK developers see this please fix it.

**Instead of this:**

```
  let response = await client
    .api('/me/outlook/tasks?$top=25000')
    .header("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"")
    .header('Prefer', `outlook.timezone="${timeZone}"`)
    .version('beta')
    .get();
```

**You MUST do this:**

```
  let response = await client
    .api('/me/outlook/tasks?$top=25000')
    .header("Prefer", `IdType="ImmutableId", outlook.timezone="${timeZone}"`)
    .version('beta')
    .get();
```

I guess setting the second Prefer header overrides the first one and consequentially only the second one is sent. Unfortunately, I've discovered this right after I implemented the solution via OpenTypeExtension.

Comment: @equallymounted You mention "MS Graph SDK developers", but is this actually related to the MS Graph _SDK_? I don't really know node but it looks like you are talking directly to the Graph API (not using the SDK) and that the issue was overwriting headers while using the Node Http client. This seems like standard and appropriate behavior for an HTTP client.

Comment: Thanks @equallyamounted my issue was that I was setting the `Prefer` header on the email message itself, not the Graph API call.